# How to index document I want to query multiple random fields dynamodb boto?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have the following in Dynamo:

```
{
username: "Joe",
account_type: "standard",
favorite_food: "Veggies",
favorite_sport: "Hockey",
favorite_person: "Steve",
date_created: <utc-milliseconds>,
record_type: "Person"
}
```

My table was created as follows:

```
Table('persons', schema=[HashKey('record_type')], global_indexes=[GlobalAllIndex('IndexOne', parts=[HashKey('favorite_food')])])
```

I want to be able to perform queries where I can query for:

```
favorite_food = "Meat", favorite_sport="Hockey"
```

or just

```
favorite_food = "Meat", date_created > <some date in utc-milliseconds>
```

or even just:
     favorite_food = "Meat"

or

```
   account_type: "premium", favorite_food: "Veggies"
```

How many indices should I be creating for global, secondary, etc. I would like to be able to perform a "query" as opposed to a scan if possible, but I cannot be sure what a user would query. I just want a list of all the "usernames" that match the query.

Comment: don't use dynamodb for such queries

Comment: Why and whats the point of dynamo then? MongoDB can support this without indexing... am I missing something here?

Comment: dynamo and mongo are key value storages, they both do not support quick scan by any column combination